# how to build a url to filter a list available on Easy Tabs

Tags: url, 2019, sharepoint-list-filter

SharePoint 2019 + [Easy Tab](https://www.markrackley.net/2015/08/16/sharepoint-tabbed-web-partshillbillytabs-3-0/)

Have 4x Tabs with same columns of data, looking to build a url that filters the data of lists on all tabs automatically.

On each tab the column can be filtered and javascript will generate a unique url that is reuseable but it's not a pretty url.

Having searched have discovered a format, but it won't work and maybe it is because there is whitespace in the reference values:

?FilterField1=First%20Name&FilterValue1=Bob

Acquired this approach from [this site](https://natechamberlain.com/2020/05/09/how-to-filter-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-using-url-parameters/)

This was also applied to the list, and the it will not work, tried using a simple parameter that contains no whitespace it also fails. So this might not be the best solution.

Does anyone have wisdom and knowledge that can be shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the list page

1. Open list settings
2. Open the column to filter
3. Review the url to obtain the field name that SharePoint has stored in the parameters

`?Field=[Field Name]`

Use the value above in the filter parameter below

```
?FilterField1=[Field Name]&FilterValue1=Bob
```

All issues resolved, and best part all tabs are filtered using a single set of parameters.